# I cannot get this Jquery Image ComboBox to Work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, combobox

Im trying to use this plugin:

http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown

I cannot get it to work in my file.  I copied and pasted the code from the example files and made the necessary links to the js and css files just to test, and i still cant get it to work. Everytime i run it, i get this error:

```
Error: Result of expression '$(".mydds").msDropDown' [undefined] is not a function
```

The script im using to run the file is:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function showvalue(arg) {
    alert(arg);
    //arg.visible(false);
}


$(document).ready(function() {

try {
        oHandler = $(".mydds").msDropDown().data("dd");
        oHandler.visible(true);
        //alert($.msDropDown.version);
        //$.msDropDown.create("body select");
        $("#ver").html($.msDropDown.version);
        } catch(e) {
            alert("Error: "+e.message);
        }
})

</script>
```

Why am I getting these errors and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax seems to be fine.

Can you make sure that the `msDropDown` js file is included and is available in the page.

You can use firefox(firebug), chrome and IE8(dev tool) to find out whether the file is downloaded and the plugin is available in the client.

Or

A nasty way will be

```
alert($("").msDropDown)
```

or

```
alert(typeof $("").msDropDown) -- function
```

Put this before you call the `msDropDown()`, it should alert with the function definition.

Comment: I cannot get the jquery.dd.js file to load for some reason, even though the link to it is correct as far as i can see. All the other js files load ok. Why is this?

Comment: Can you post the include scripts for javascript files?